# JAVA: error: unexpected type

Tags: java

```
public abstract class Character{

public enum Type{ ROGUE, PALADIN, JACKIE_CHEN, SKELETON, GOBLIN, WIZARD}

private String name;
private int hitPoints;
private int strength;
private Weapon weapon;
//other attributes

//methods

public Character(Type characterType){
    switch(characterType){
        case ROGUE:
            //set the attributes for a Rogue
            name = "Rogue";
            // TODO: set other attributes
            hitPoints = 55;
            strength = 8;
            Weapon rogue = new Weapon("Short Sword", 1, 4);

            break;
        case PALADIN:
            //set the attributes for a Rogue
            name = "Paladin";
            // TODO: set other attributes
            hitPoints = 35;
            strength = 14;
            Weapon paladin = new Weapon("Long Sword",3,7);
            break;
        case JACKIE_CHEN:
            name = "Jackie Chen";
            hitPoints =45;
            strength = 10;
            Weapon jackie = new Weapon("Jump Kick",2, 6);
            break;
        case SKELETON:
            name = "Skeleton";
            hitPoints = 25;
            strength = 3;
            Weapon skeleton = new Weapon("Short Sword" ,1, 4);
            break;
        case GOBLIN:
            name = "Goblin";
            hitPoints = 25;
            strength = 4;
            Weapon goblin = new Weapon("Axe",2,6);
            break;
        case WIZARD:
            name = "Wizard";
            hitPoints = 40;
            strength = 8;
            Weapon wizard = new Weapon("Fire Blast", 4, 10);
            break;
    }
}

public String getName(){
    return name;
}

public int getHitPoints(){
    return hitPoints;
}
public int getStrength(){
    return strength;
}
public void setStrength(int _strength){
    this.strength =_strength;
}
public void setWeapon(Weapon _weapon){
    this.weapon = _weapon;

}

public void attack(){

}

public void increaseHitPoints(){

}
public void decreaseHitPoints(){

}
/*public boolean isDefeated(){

}*/
```

}

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Random;
public class Player extends Character{
// attributes for the plauer class
// initilizes the fields
private int coins;
private Potion[] inventory;
Random randomNums = new Random();
Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

//methods

public Player(Type playerType){
    super(playerType);
    coins = 0;
    inventory = new Potion[5];
}   

public void increaseStrength(int strengthIncrease){
    enemy.getHitPoints() -= playerATK;


}
public int getCoins(){
    return coins;
}
public void increaseCoins(int coins){

}
public void decreaseCoins(int coins){

}
public void addToInventory(String a, Type potion){

}
public void removeFromInventory(int index){

}
public void displayInventory(){

}
/*public int getNumOpenSlots(){
    return numOpenSlots;
}*/

public void battleMinion(Enemy enemy){


    Enemy goblin = new Enemy(Character.Type.GOBLIN);
    int playerDamage =0, playerATK =0, enemyATK =0, enemyDamage =0;

    if (enemy.getName() == "Goblin" && getName()=="Rogue"){
        for (int i = 1; i <= goblin.getNumGoblins(); i++)
        {
          System.out.printf("***%s vs %s %d***\n", getName(), enemy.getName(), i);

          while(enemy.getHitPoints() > 0 && getHitPoints() > 0)
          {
            playerDamage = randomNums.nextInt(Weapon.SHORT_SWORD_MAX - Weapon.SHORT_SWORD_MIN + 1) + Weapon.SHORT_SWORD_MIN;
            playerATK = getStrength() + playerDamage;
            enemy.getHitPoints() -= playerATK;
            System.out.printf("%s attacks with ATK = %d + %d = %d\n", getName(), getStrength(), playerDamage, playerATK);
            System.out.printf("%s HP is now %d - %d = %d\n\n", enemy.getName(), enemy.getHitPoints() + playerATK, playerATK, enemy.getHitPoints());

            if (enemy.getHitPoints() <= 0)
              break;

            enemyDamage = randomNums.nextInt(Weapon.AXE_MAX - Weapon.AXE_MIN + 1) + Weapon.AXE_MAX;
            enemyATK = enemy.getStrength() + enemyDamage;
            getHitPoints() -= enemyATK;
            System.out.printf("%s attacks with ATK = %d + %d = %d\n", getName(), enemy.getStrength(), enemyDamage, enemyATK);
            System.out.printf("%s HP is now %d - %d = %d\n\n", getName(), getHitPoints() + enemyATK, enemyATK, getHitPoints());
          } // end of while loop

          if (getHitPoints() > 0){
            System.out.printf("%s defeated %s %d!\n\n", getName(), enemy.getName(), i);
            coins = randomNums.nextInt((50 - 30) + 1) + 30;
            System.out.println(getName() + " gains " + coins + " gold coins!\n");
            //player[4] += coins;
          }
          else
          {
            System.out.printf("--%s is defeated in battle!--\n\nGAME OVER\n", getName());
            System.exit(0);
          }

          if(i <= goblin.getNumGoblins() - 1){
            System.out.println("Press enter to continue...");
            keyboard.nextLine(); 
          }
        }
    }
```

Error is as follows

> ./Player.java:59: error: unexpected type
>                       enemy.getHitPoints() -= playerATK;
>                                         ^
>         required: variable
>         found:    value
>       ./Player.java:68: error: unexpected type
>                       getHitPoints() -= enemyATK;

I know this is wrong, but what is the reason behind this? Also I have

```
public void increaseHitPoints(){

}
public void decreaseHitPoints(){

}
```

these two class in my character class, I don't how to code to make this work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`getHitPoints()` is a method that returns a value. You can't assign anything to that expression, and the `-=` operator performs both subtraction and assignment.

Instead of

```
getHitPoints() -= playerATK;
```

write

```
setHitPoints (getHitPoints() - playerATK);
```

or

```
decreaseHitPointsBy (playerATK); // this approach would require a corresponding 
                                 // increaseHitPointsBy (value) method
```

Comment: but I don't have a setHitPoints, and If I want to use decreaseHitPointsBy(playerATK), what do I need in the                        
public void increaseHitPoints(){

}
public void decreaseHitPoints(){

}

Comment: @michaeliop You need to add method like the suggested ones, which would modify the value of the `hitPoints` variable.

Comment: this is what I have in my Player class right now
decreaseHitPoints(getHitPoints()) -= playerATK;
and this is what I have in my Character class right now
public void decreaseHitPoints(int pointDecrease){
     this.hitPoints = this.hitPoints - pointDecrease;
}
The error shows
./Player.java:60: error: unexpected type
          decreaseHitPoints(getHitPoints()) -= playerATK;
                           ^
  required: variable
  found:    value

Comment: @michaeliop It shouldn't be `decreaseHitPoints(getHitPoints()) -= playerATK;`. It should be `decreaseHitPoints(playerATK);`

Comment: so how could the hitPoints actually decrease if i code as this

Comment: Ok, I see..... Just a long night, my brain isn't work right now. Thanks for your help